# Putting a function's data into blade, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have following code in a function in my laravel controller:

```
try {
    return json_encode(FormBuilder::BuildOrderForm($dealer, $aa, $form));
} catch (OPSException $e) {
    return json_encode(['error' => $e->getUserMessage()]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

This is returning the data I need in a JSON object. I'm trying to recreate this to build the data within html code in my laravel blade. what's the proper way to put the above `FormBuilder::BuildOrderForm($dealer, $aa, $form)` into my blade here:

```
@section('content')

<h3 style="font-size: 26px; padding: 10px 0;"> {{ <!-- This is where I need the data --> }} </h3>
<p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" ></p>

<div class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10">
        <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 100%;">

        </ul>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**The whole class in controller:**

```
class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $ordering_access = AttributesList::with('attr_info')
            ->where('attr_id', AttributesList::attrId('ordering_toggle'))
            ->where('data', $this->dealer)
            ->count();

        if ($ordering_access > 0) {
            \Session::flash('error_message', "You are not allowed to order. Please contact your CSR!");
            $attributeid = 100000;
        } else {
            $attributeid = 6;
        }
        Access::Check($attributeid);
        $this->dealer = Access::getAttrValue('dealer_num');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $forms = FormBuilder::Orderforms($this->dealer);
        return view('Shop.Order.index')->with('forms', $forms);
    }


    public function show($id)
    {
        $cart_num = Access::getAttrValue('cart_num');
        if (!$cart_num) {
            $cart = 0;
        } else {
            $find_cart = Cart::find($cart_num);
            if ($find_cart  && $find_cart->orderform == $id) {
                $cart = $cart_num;
            } else {
                $cart = 0;
            }
        }
        return view('Shop.Order.show')
            ->with('dealer', $this->dealer)
            ->with('cart', $cart)
            ->with('form', $id);
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'dealer' => 'required|numeric',
            'form' => 'required',
        ]);

        // check to make sure this dealer can order from this formid
        $dealer = Input::get('dealer');
        $form = Input::get('form');

        $aa = FormBuilder::getcompanyfromform($form) + 0;

        $comp = CustomerDataNew::getcomp($dealer);

        if (!in_array($aa, $comp)) {
            return "Error: Dealer can't use this form";
        }

        try {
            return json_encode(FormBuilder::BuildOrderForm($dealer, $aa, $form));
        } catch (OPSException $e) {
            return json_encode(['error' => $e->getUserMessage()]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where in your code is your try block located? A Controller? a Class?

Comment: Sorry, the class of my controller. I updated with the whole class. But yes, this is the controller for that view

Comment: Ok... Another problem... what route are you accessing, and what method in your controller is bound to such route?

Comment: The route, called routes.shop.php is ```/**
         * Build Order Form
         */
        Route::post('build', 'Shop\BuildOrderFormController@store')
            ->name('shop.order.build');``` and the method is ```store```

Comment: Is that the route executing when DISPLAYING the form, or when SUBMITTING the form?

Comment: Also, what is the name of that view you are trying to render data to? Is it `Shop.Order.show` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just returning the encoded data, therefore you must be seeing a bunch of JSON (or errors if you are catching any exceptions).

In order to display any data, you have to do the same thing you are doing in your `show()` method, that is, return a view and render any data inside that particular view or partial.

Try the following:

```
public function store(Request $request) {

...

    try {

        $data = json_encode(FormBuilder::BuildOrderForm($dealer, $aa, $form));
        return view('Shop.Order.show')->with('data', $data);

    } catch (OPSException $e) {
        return $this->returnFromException($e->getUserMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->returnFromException($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public function returnFromException($error)
{
    $error = json_encode(['error' => $error]);
    return view('Shop.Order.show')->with('error', $error);
}
```

Now, in your view, using Blade you can display the data like so:

```
@section('content')

    @if(isset($error))    
        <h3 style="font-size: 26px; padding: 10px 0;">{{ dd($error) }} </h3>
    @else if(isset($data))
        {{ dd($data) }}
    @endif
    <p class="uk-text-muted" style="font-size: 20px;" ></p>

    <div class="uk-grid">
        <div class="uk-width-2-10">
            <ul style="margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; float: left; width: 100%;">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Note that you will have to get rid of the `dd()`s in the Blade view, since it with halt the HTML rendering. You will have to use something like `@foreach()` to render an array or JSON.

I hope this helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 

use App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName;
echo ControllerName::functionName();

 ?>
```

The functionName should have the 'static' keyword e.g

Controller function:

```
public static function functionName() {
return "Hello World!";
}
```

I saw the code from this link [How to call a controller function inside a view in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332784/how-to-call-a-controller-function-inside-a-view-in-laravel-5)

for example:

Route:

```
Route::get('checkTheTest', ['as' => 'checkrequest', 'uses' => 'MiscController@myTest']);
```

MiscController:

```
 public static function requesting($request){
        return 'error ' .$request;
    }
```

blade template view:

```
<?php
 use App\Http\Controllers\MiscController;
 echo MiscController::requesting('hello world'); ?>
```

OUTPUT:

```
error hello world
```

Comment: What do you mean, please explain.

Comment: I have added example above