# How to call a controller from view in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 in which i have to call a controller from view blade. But it showing me parse error. Please find my code.

**Controller name:ReportController(path=app/Http/Controllers/Admin/ReportController)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
//send email use helper
use App\Helpers\MyHelperFunction;

 public static function my($args){
        // do your stuff or return something.
        echo $args."I am called on view.";
    }
?>
```

**View:customerorders.blade.php**

```
<?php 
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReportController;
     echo ReportController::my('hello'); 
?>
```

I facing this error:

> Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception,
>   caught ErrorException: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use'
>   (T_USE)
>   (View:/opt/lampp/htdocs/buddyiq_dev/resources/views/Admin/reports/customerorders.blade.php)

I refer above code from below stack url.

[How to call a controller function inside a view in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332784/how-to-call-a-controller-function-inside-a-view-in-laravel-5)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I just tried this on one of my Laravel setups. I'm not sure if it's the best approach but it works.

Declare your function as

```
public static function my($args)
{
       echo $args."I am called on view.";
}
```

which you already did. then call it from the view as `{{App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReportController::my($args)}}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using ajax to call to function in a controller, then get the respones and push it to view.
About respones, remember to put `return` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

If your motivation for calling a controller method is just to output a string a controller may be inappropriate. Controllers bind models and views together.

[image]

[image source:  Basic Laravel 5 MVC](https://selftaughtcoders.com/from-idea-to-launch/lesson-17/laravel-5-mvc-application-in-10-minutes/)

Views really shouldn't be aware of controllers methods. You might be better off investigating view **helper methods**.

This is also answered in the question you link to

> If you have a function which is being used at multiple places you
>   should define it in helpers file

This Q/A is helpful [Best practices for custom helpers on Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290332/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5)

Answer (score -2):

Use the absolute path instead relative path, you can use this as like below,

```
 \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReportController
```

but you have used  `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReportController`, please change it in every places.

Comment: did you fix the paths to absolute?

Comment: did you properly configured autoload file, check whether this is there,  "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },