# call functions from Controller class to any view

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to be able to call some functions defined in  Controller Class, to any view. All controllers extends Controller class.

For example i want to call the function which is define in Controller class:

```
public function makeSeoLink($str)
{
    // code logic....
    return strtolower($str);
}
```

where HomeController extends it:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
  return view('home.homepage');
{
```

in homepage view {{ makeSeoLink('asfasfs') }} or {{ $this->makeSeoLink('asfasfs') }} not working to call that function:

```
"Call to undefined function makeSeoLink()"
```

What i have done wrong?

Comment: Dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332784/how-to-call-a-controller-function-inside-a-view-in-laravel-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using an instance of controller class in index method works:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Controller $tools){
      return view('home.homepage')->with('tools', $tools);
    }  
}
```

and in the view just use the variable $tools to call the method

```
 {{ $tools->makeSeoLink('') }}
```