# Pass data in an included view with Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5.6, I'm trying to get the number of received links a logged-in user may have in my application.

```
public function getReceivedLinksCount() {
    return $count = App\Link::where([
                ['recipient_id', Auth::id()],
                ['sender_id', '!=', Auth::id()]
            ])->count();
}
```

So far, so good. Question is not about that piece of code, but *where* I can use it. I'd like to display this counter on the navigation bar of the website (Facebook's style) which is in my `header.blade.php` which is included in every page.

I'd like to do it with a clean code, of course. It seems like I need to use View Composers but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it, and not sure on how the code is supposed to look.

Comment: on header.blade.php call the getReceivedLinksCount method

Comment: here is how to call it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332784/how-to-call-a-controller-function-inside-a-view-in-laravel-5

Comment: is that really a clean way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('layouts.header', function ($view) {
            $view->with('variable_name', \App\Path-To-Your-Model::something());
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer works well but with more recent (I guess) code : I used `View::composer` instead of `view()->composer`. Thanks.

Comment: if use View:: you need add -> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View; to top of your class, use view() helper no need add that line and is same effect, and the difference of View::share is View::share is global the variable, view()->composer('name of the blade_this accept array too') means ONLY generate the variable when load the header blade

Comment: so for example if you load admin_header.blade.php, you don't have this variable, because you may don't need that

Answer (score 0):

You can share a value across all views by using View::share(), see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

For example

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $linksCount = Link::getReceivedLinksCount();
        View::share('linksCount', $linksCount);
    }

    ...

}
```

This works well if you want to set the value **everywhere**. Personally, I would set the value in the constructor of a 'BaseController' that gets extended by other controllers. This makes the code more discoverable because most people would expect view values to be set in a controller. And it's also a bit more flexible if you plan on having a section of your app that doesn't require that value to be computed.

Comment: Is it the same as doing `@inject('count', 'App\Http\Controllers\LinkController')` like explained in [Blade's injection doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#service-injection)? I find it a little bit ugly, no?

Comment: I find the controller approach better because you wouldn't have to update the views if you refactor the code that generates the count (for example change the class name or method name or whatever)

Comment: Ok! What's the difference between your code and the other answer from kenken9999 ? Also, what would you recommend between adding the piece of code in AppServiceProvider or in a separate service provider?