# Using two variable how to access controller function

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to access a controller function from blade file in laravel.

My Code:

**Blade.php**

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\myController;
$newControl = new myController;

$function = 'myfunction()';

echo $newControl->$function;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a controller function inside a view in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332784/how-to-call-a-controller-function-inside-a-view-in-laravel-5)

Comment: There's probably another issue here which is that you shouldn't put such logic in your view. Your controller should be the one to call these functions.

Comment: then how to call the function because use dynamic