# how to pass value from blade to controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, query-builder

I am new in laravel, could you please help me in below situation,
i have a function which takes three arguments

```
public function myfunction (Request $request)
{
    $first=$request->first;
$second=$request->second;
$third=$request->third;
{some calculation here }
return view('report/myrepo1,.......)}
```

now i have blade where we have for each loop of some other $variable like this

```
@foreach($var as $v)
 <tr>{{<td>$v->first}}</td>
<td>{{$v->second}}</td>
<td>{{$v->third}}</td>
<td>{{  ?????  //How to cal the function which i wrote in controller }} 
//if i am doing calling a function as we do in C or C++ it show error}}
    //like this {{myfunction($value->first,$value->second,$value->third)}}
```

any idea how to solve this kind of problem
thanks

Comment: see this answer use any one method as per your situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332784/how-to-call-a-controller-function-inside-a-view-in-laravel-5

Comment: your method does not take 3 arguments by the way, it takes one and its a Request

Comment: but i like to pass three arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a controller function inside a view in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332784/how-to-call-a-controller-function-inside-a-view-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a custom blade directive using Blade:: facade inside a service provider i.e. `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` something like below:

In boot method of your `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`

```
//Blade directive to myfunction.
Blade::directive('myfunction', function ($a1, $a2, $a3) {
    //Do calculations you want here and return back..
    return $a1 + $a2 + $a3;
});
```

In your blade file

```
@foreach($var as $v)
    <td>{{ @myfunction($v->first, $v->second, $v->third) }} </td>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you must call Controller function in your blade file
as an example:

```
{{\App\TestController::TestFunction($item->id)}}
```